# C# Deleting rows of excel sheet that contain variable not working

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, rows

So below you will see the code im using to iterate through a excel spreadsheet and find every row that contains *x*. For some reason not only does the operation STOP at the very last row and not finish the operation, allowing me to save my edits and close the handle to excel, but also seems to be skipping rows. It will go through, say 25k rows that need to be deleted, yet only delete 12.5k. Im sure im doing something simple wrong here, so im hoping a few sets of eyes on it can spot my mistake. My code:

```
void startOperation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Beginning start operations..." + searchText);
        Console.WriteLine("Opening Workbook: " + filePath);

        // create excel-instance:
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // open the concrete file:
        Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@filePath);
        //MessageBox.Show(filePath);
        // select worksheet. NOT zero-based!!:
        _Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(xlWorksheet.Name));
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;

        int numRows = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

        numRowsDeleted = 0;
        nullCounter = 0;
        var percentageComp = new Decimal(.001);

        //Parallel.For(1, numRows, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, i =>
        for (currRow = 1; currRow <= numRows; currRow++)
        {
            percentageComp = ((decimal)currRow / (decimal)numRows) * 100;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows: " + numRows);
            Console.WriteLine("Checking Row #: " + currRow);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows Deleted: " + numRowsDeleted);
            Console.WriteLine("Percentage Comp: " + percentageComp.ToString("#.##"));

            //Create Worksheet Range
            range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[currRow, 2];

            //MessageBox.Show(cellValue);
            if (currRow == numRows)
            {
                closeOperation(xlApp, xlWorkbook);
                break;
            }

            if (Convert.ToString(range.Value) != null)  //if (cellValue != null || cellValue != "")
            {
                cellValue = Convert.ToString(range.Value);
                //nullCounter = 0;
                //MessageBox.Show("Cell Value: " + cellValue);

                if (cellValue.Contains("MESSAGE NOT CONFIGURED"))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Cell Value: " + cellValue);
                    xlWorksheet.Rows[currRow].Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
                    numRowsDeleted++;
                    //currRow++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //currRow++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //nullCounter++;
                //currRow++;
            }


            //currRow++;
        }
    }
```

Again, your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you delete rows you should start your Loop at the last row and go up

Comment: thats amazingly simple lol. I simply changed my currRow++ to currRow-- after a row is deleted and that seemed to fix it, however it does seem to take significantly longer now to go through all rows.

Comment: because you basically doubbled the amount of rows to check

Comment: Well seeing as how i cant for the life of me get parallel looping to work with excel, how can i reduce this time?